# Using Picture or Icon instead of DataGridCheckBoxColumn in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, controls, styles

I want to change the CheckBox which is inside of a DataGridColumn into an image when it is checked and another when it is unchecked, How can i do ?
Ps: My DataGridCheckBoxColumn is defined like this:

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Priority" Binding="{Binding PRIORITY, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
```

Converter is converting bytes to boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`ElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle.aspx) and [`EditingElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle.aspx) properties to create and set a different [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) for the `CheckBox` which fits that.

e.g.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsActive}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Image MaxWidth="32" MaxHeight="32">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/Error.ico" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/Default.ico" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

This makes the column display an image based on `IsChecked`, the URIs are just hardcoded and the CheckBox is disabled because editing in the ElementStyle does not change any properties on the bound object. Its only purpose is to display the approriate image.

(*The `EditingElementStyle` is not set here so if the user clicks the cell again to edit it a normal CheckBox appears which can be checked or unchecked.*)

[image: Screencap]

Comment: Just to add that if you wish to hide the checkboxes with EditingElementStyle, it's the same code as above without this <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />

Comment: Problem here is that image is not changing when checked/unchecked if the cell is not previously selected/focused. So how to solve this? any idea?

Comment: @user1624552: The `ElementStyle` should work without that, did you set the `EditingElementStyle` instead?

Comment: @H.B. Yes I did. I put both, ElementStyle as above in your example and also EditingElementStyle (without <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />. First time you click on the checkbox column, checkbox is not checked/unchecked, it needs a second click. Once checkbox column has the focus there is no problem.