# Creating DataGridColumn which displays 1 of 2 different pictures, fed from a datatable

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

So i got this DataGrid in which i manually defined all the columns:

```
     <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" <lotsofstuff> ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="firstname" x:Name="firstname" Binding="{Binding Path=firstname}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="lastname" x:Name="lastname" Binding="{Binding Path=lastname}" />

                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="sick" x:Name="sick" Binding="{Binding Path=sick}"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="vacation" x:Name="vacation" Binding="{Binding Path=vacation}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Filling it with a datatable works fine so far:

```
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.DefaultView;
```

But in my datatable exists is a 5th bool column and i want my DataGrid to display a certain picture if it's true and another one if it's false.

How do i do that? I have no clue.

Comment: Check this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901107/using-picture-or-icon-instead-of-datagridcheckboxcolumn-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with an `Image` within the `CellTemplate`. The Image `Source` property will be a binding expression, something like this:

```
{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource DataToImageConverter}}
```

Create an implementation of `IValueConverter` for `DataToImageConverter` (for example) to take the DataItem {Binding} - which will include your bool value, and within the converter you can return whatever image you like.