# Change image inside CheckBox for null value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I have a DataGrid, of which 1 column is a bool and I display that as a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.  I would like use a different image than the default for null values (grey checkmark in Windows Server; blue box in Win 7, etc). Or if I could have a solid box of another color (orange, say), that would work too.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Either use a `DataTemplate` for the column or override the `CheckBox` ControlTemplate. What have you tried?

Comment: @HighCore - I haven't tried much. I am not familiar with this area of WPF (customizing default controls/etc), so I'm not even totally sure where to start looking!

Comment: Similar question that can give you some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901107/using-picture-or-icon-instead-of-datagridcheckboxcolumn-in-wpf